# What is the equivalent to "cp --backup=numbered" in alpine linux?

Tags: linux, cp, busybox

I'm porting a script from ubuntu to alpine linux 3.4 (docker image).
I can't seem to find a way to do "cp --backup=numbered" in alpine.
Is there any way to install a more complete "cp"?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the answer to this one...

`apk add --upgrade coreutils`

It seems that --backup is an option of GNU coreutils, which is not installed by default in the alpine linux 3.4 docker image.
Adding it via the command above sorted it.

Comment: Would this partially defeat the purpose of alpine? Would this upgrade every linux utility? ping, nc, find, grep etc?

Comment: @ray Yes, it would _partially_ defeat the purpose of alpine, but none of _those_ specific tools are part of `coreutils`

Answer (score 1):

Alpine Linux uses busybox, which has a built-in cp command, as well as other [commands](https://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html).
For GNU commands, they can be easily installed via apk package manager.